# Вычислить возраст и поместить результат в поле. .NET

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

Дано:

```
<sq8:DatePicker runat="server" ID="dateDatePicker">
   <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="get_current_age"></ClientEvents>
</sq8:DatePicker>

<sq:BindableControl runat="server" TargetControlID="dateDatePicker" DataField="Date"></sq:BindableControl>

</div>
<div class="sqf-col-xs-4 sqf-control-group-v">
<sq8:Label runat="server" Text="Age" ID="lblAge"></sq8:Label>

<sq8:NumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtAge"></sq8:NumericTextBox>
```

Нужно достать дату из DatePicker и поставить соответствующую цифру в поле `NumericTextBox`.

Comment: Пока редактировал ваш пример, заметил, что `div` тег не правильно записан. Так положено?

Comment: .так это ж просто вырезка из кода. вверху нет открывашки, внизу закрывашки

Comment: Извините, но по выерзкам кода, которые не валидны, мало кто сможет вам помочь.